# Discrete Math Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is one of my midterm review questions. I am not sure where to start. Should I use induction to prove that, if so, how should I do it?

Recall that $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ . Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ and $B = \mathbb{N}\cup\{-1,0\}$ have the same cardinality.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This exercise makes no sense whatsoever. What is $B$ finally? Is it $\{2,3,4,5,6,8\}$? Or is it $N \cup \{-1,0\}$?

Comment: Sorry, B is not there. I edited the question. hopefully it make sense now

Answer (score 2):

Make a bijection $f: B \rightarrow N$ like this.

$f(x)=x+2$

Now you just need to prove that it's surjective and injective and you're done, the cardinalities would then be the same.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment, I am just wondering where is the x+2 function come from, can we just assume the function?

Comment: You know if you want you can make any number of functions on given sets (finite if sets are finite). But if it happens to be a bijection (like the one here), then this would mean the sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: @Anonymous What do you mean can we just assume the function? We defined this function. We then want to show it's a bijection.

Comment: @Mike, Sorry for the misunderstanding, what I mean is that I am not sure how he come up with f(x) = x + 2

Comment: Well it's easy. Line up all of the elements of $\mathbb{N}$, you get $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\cdots$. Now line up elements of $\mathbb{B}$, you get $-1,0,1,2,3,\cdots$. You can plainly see that $B$ is $\mathbb{N}$ shifted right two times. There are sets, where the functions are not so trivial though (like mapping $(3,5)$ to $(1,100)$.

Comment: ahh I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is false as stated. Presumably you meant $\mathbb N = \{1, 2, 3, 4, \dots \}$.
It defines B in question: $B = \mathbb N \cup \{-1,0\}$: i.e. $B = \{-1, 0, 1, 2, \dots\}$.

To prove that two sets have the same cardinality, you need to demonstrate a bijection between them. What can you do to $B$ to send it to $\mathbb N$?